# OnServiceConnected never called

Tags: android, service

I've searched through dozens of links on this site about this exact same problem, but for the life of me I can't seem to figure it out. I'm just binding my activity to my service, yet when I try to call a method of that service (yes, it is public), I get a NullPointerException. Here's the code that I have. Please, help.

Here's my service itself:

```
public class ParseService extends Service {

public static ParseUser user;

private final IBinder binder = new LocalBinder();

public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
    public ParseService getService() {
        return ParseService.this;
    }
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return binder;
}
```

And here's my activity code that binds to the service:

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    bindToService();
}

private void bindToService() {
    Log.v("Miles", "bind to service");
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ParseService.class);
    getApplicationContext().bindService(intent, serviceConnection, Context.BIND_DEBUG_UNBIND);
}

private ServiceConnection serviceConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder binder) {
        Log.v("Miles", "on service connected");
        parseService = ((ParseService.LocalBinder)binder).getService();
        serviceBound = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.v("Miles", "on service disconnected");
        serviceBound = false;
    }
};
```

And the NullPointerException log. When I click a menu item in my Activity, it calls a method in my service ParseService. This method is currently just a dummy "LOG" statement purely for testing purposes.

08-05 16:56:57.788: E/AndroidRuntime(1205): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-05 16:56:57.788: E/AndroidRuntime(1205): Process: max.out, PID: 1205
08-05 16:56:57.788: E/AndroidRuntime(1205): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-05 16:56:57.788: E/AndroidRuntime(1205):     at maxOut.StatsScreen.onOptionsItemSelected(StatsScreen.java:125)
08-05 16:56:57.788: E/AndroidRuntime(1205):     at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2608)
08-05 16:56:57.788: E/AndroidRuntime(1205):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onMenuItemSelected(FragmentActivity.java:373)
08-05 16:56:57.788: E/AndroidRuntime(1205):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.onMenuItemSelected(PhoneWindow.java:1012)
08-05 16:56:57.788: E/AndroidRuntime(1205):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:735)
08-05 16:56:57.788: E/AndroidRuntime(1205):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:152)
08-05 16:56:57.788: E/AndroidRuntime(1205):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:874)
08-05 16:56:57.788: E/AndroidRuntime(1205):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.ActionMenuView.invokeItem(ActionMenuView.java:546)
08-05 16:56:57.788: E/AndroidRuntime(1205):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.ActionMenuItemView.onClick(ActionMenuItemView.java:129)
08-05 16:56:57.788: E/AndroidRuntime(1205):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4466)
08-05 16:56:57.788: E/AndroidRuntime(1205):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18537)
08-05 16:56:57.788: E/AndroidRuntime(1205):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
08-05 16:56:57.788: E/AndroidRuntime(1205):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
08-05 16:56:57.788: E/AndroidRuntime(1205):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
08-05 16:56:57.788: E/AndroidRuntime(1205):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5102)
08-05 16:56:57.788: E/AndroidRuntime(1205):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-05 16:56:57.788: E/AndroidRuntime(1205):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
08-05 16:56:57.788: E/AndroidRuntime(1205):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
08-05 16:56:57.788: E/AndroidRuntime(1205):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
08-05 16:56:57.788: E/AndroidRuntime(1205):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: Your debug log containing the NPE message will go a long way to getting help.

Comment: Of course. I'll add it into my original post.